# Threejs Geometry color

Tags: javascript, three.js

I set the geometry color with an HEX value

```
RichGeometry.prototype = new THREE.Geometry();

RichGeometry.prototype.constructor = RichGeometry;
function RichGeometry(c) {
c = typeof c !== 'undefined' ? c : 0x00C020;     // color

THREE.Geometry.call(this);

this.color = c;

}
```

but when I get the value from the created object, it returns me an RGB value like this 16711680. Why? How can I get the HEX value?

```
var geometry0 = new RichGeometry(0xff0000);
console.log(geometry0.color);// it returns rgb value like this 16711680
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the color as an instance of [`THREE.Color`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Color):

```
function RichGeometry(c) {

    c = (typeof c !== 'undefined') ? c : 0x00C020;

    THREE.Geometry.call(this);

    this.color = new THREE.Color(c);

}
```

Then you can retrieve different representations of the color using the methods on `THREE.Color`. For your example, try:

```
var geometry0 = new RichGeometry(0xff0000);
console.log('0x' + geometry0.color.getHexString());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use 0xff0000 it is a representation of an integer (i.e. 16711680) which is different than when you use "0xff0000" which is a string. So depends what you want to do.

Comment: I need to get the initial value I put in constructor. If I put 0xff0000 I would like to retrieve the same and not in RGB like now.

Comment: put it as a string not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
> foo = 16711680
16711680
> '0x'+foo.toString(16)
'0xff0000'
```

Convert the number to a hex string and prepend the '0x'

you may want to wrap this in a getter like:

```
   this.__defineGetter__('color', function(){
        return '0x'+this.color.toString(16)
    });
```